# List of HTML element own changed styles

Tags: html, css

Since shadow DOM is still in development and not supported by all browsers, I'm trying to create a kind of "reset / barrier" style class definition to reset all styles. The MDN docu has a list of all attribute names: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/Reference with their initial (default) value. But HTML elements (here is a list: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element) have sometimes their own modified style values, like a `<h3>` with top and bottom margins and bigger text size or a `<i>` which has italic text style:

[image: <h3> element]

[image: <i> element]

Unfortunately, setting CSS attributes to `initial` on such elements sets their values to the *general* default values (the values from the list above), and not to the element's "own" default values. For example: Setting `display: initial` to a DIV will set the value to `inline`, since this is the [*general* default value](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/display) for the `display` attribute, instead to `block`. Also, IE [doesn't even know](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781508%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#keywords) the general CSS values `initial` (and `inherit` is not what I'm looking for; `unset` is just a combination of `inherit`+`initial`).

So my question is: Is there a way (for all browsers and with pure CSS) to reset CSS attribute values to their element's default values? And if not: Does somebody know or has a full list of changed attributes for each [HTML element](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element), so I can at least set the styles manually? Maybe something like this:

```
.div {
    display: block;
}

.i {
    font-style: italic;
}

.h3 {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* ... */
```

I already created a long list to reset all values manually, even for IE (that damn browser makes it so hard... it doesn't know `initial` and it does not know the `all` attribute). Before I start to find out myself, such a list would be helpful.

Comment: What's wrong with Eric Meyers [CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)?

Comment: @LGSon Hmm, looks interesting, thanks. But it seems to be incomplete. A very minimalistic solution (like the author says himself there). For example, the mentioned `display` attribute for tags like H1-H6 or DIV are not resetted. Also it does not reset all CSS attributes (there are *many* of them - see the list from MDN). And it shall reset for one sub-element, not entire document (similar to a shadow DOM abstraction layer, so no parent elements or global CSS instructions "pre-set" undefined attributes). I need to reset as much attributes as possible.

Comment: Well, there is no magic bullet to do that. We were all hoping that `initial` would do the trick, but it turned out not to. Ditto with `unset`. So if you really want to reset all the properties of all the elements, you will have to copy the entire default stylesheet of your browser.

Comment: I didn't asked for a magic bullet. I just need a list with the element specific attribute changes. I created the list to reset all attributes already (even for IE) and it works fine. Right now I'm creating the list for each element by comparing the computed styles against the default styles. Luckily there are less of them than the CSS attributes. It's a lot of work but it's progressing. Simply copying the entire style list for each element would be too much. If someone is interested, I could post the result here.